# How to efficiently return minimum value from subquery after being filtered by parent query column

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle12c

I'm starting with a very large and complex query that essentially returns a bunch of data regarding surgical logs, but ultimately each row represents one log and has one unique log ID. To this query I'm trying to add the patient's most recent weight measurement prior to surgery. Unfortunately, I'm having a difficult time efficiently joining this data.

Here is a simplified representation of the query:

```
SELECT or_log.log_id, or_log.start_dt, weight.*
FROM or_log
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT measurement.log_id, measurement.recorded_time, ROUND(measurement.meas_value,2) AS "WEIGHT",
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY measurement.log_id ORDER BY measurement.recorded_time DESC) AS r
        FROM measurement
        WHERE measurement.type='weight'
    ) weight ON weight.log_id=or_log.log_id AND weight.r=1
```

This actually works fine but does not restrict the weight measurements to those prior to surgery, it just gives the most recent weight measurement. What I need to add is a where clause to the subquery that says `weight.recorded_time <= or_log.start_dt`. The problem is that `or_log.start_dt` cannot be referenced from within the subquery. If I try to reference the or_log table (which enables me to get at `or_log.start_dt`) from within the subquery it does a full table scan on the table and takes 12 million years to run.

This seems like it should be simple but at this point I think I'm suffering from a very severe case of tunnel vision and can't see past what I've already got. I'd be grateful for some gentle nudging in the right direction!

EDIT: I should mention that I don't just need the weight scalar value from the subquery, I also need the recorded time of that weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery in your select:

```
SELECT or_log.log_id, or_log.start_dt, 
(select row_to_json(x.*) from (
 SELECT measurement.log_id, measurement.recorded_time,         ROUND(measurement.meas_value,2) AS "WEIGHT",
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY measurement.log_id ORDER BY     measurement.recorded_time DESC) AS r
        FROM measurement
        WHERE measurement.type='weight'
and measurement.log_id=or_log.log_id
) x where x.r=1)
FROM or_log
```

obviously, you'll need to do your additional filtering, but you CAN reference or_log in the inner query.

Comment: I ended up adding a bunch of scalar sub queries to handle it as you suggested... seemed cleaner that way. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This may seem too simplistic, but why not directly join the tables, then filter the row_number() result.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            or_log.log_id
          , or_log.start_dt
          , w.recorded_time
          , ROUND(w.meas_value, 2) AS "WEIGHT"
          , NVL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w.log_id ORDER BY w.recorded_time DESC), 1) AS r
      FROM or_log
            LEFT OUTER JOIN measurement w ON or_log.log_id = w.log_id
                        AND w.type = 'weight'
                        AND w.recorded_time <= or_log.start_dt
      ) d
WHERE d.r = 1
```

alternative: leave out use of NVL() and then filter for

```
d.r = 1 or d.r is null
```